# Parsing span inside div using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Given this `HTML`:

```html
<div id="cat-product-list" alt1="356623" class="product-list list_all_items_price price_new"><span id="wholesale_11_member_price" class="index-price special_price final_price" price="US$5.25"><strong class="final_price_strong">US$5.25</strong><b class="show_vip">(vip)</b></span><span id="wholesale_12_member_price" class="index-price special_price final_price" price="US$4.90" style="display: none"><strong class="final_price_strong">US$4.90</strong><b class="show_vip">(vip)</b></span><span id="wholesale_13_member_price" class="index-price special_price final_price" price="US$4.55" style="display: none"><strong class="final_price_strong">US$4.55</strong><b class="show_vip">(vip)</b></span><span id="wholesale_14_member_price" class="index-price special_price final_price" price="US$4.20" style="display: none"><strong class="final_price_strong">US$4.20</strong><b class="show_vip">(vip)</b></span><span id="shop_price_member_price_on" class="index-price shop_price" price="US$7.00"><strike>US$7.00</strike></span></div>
```

I am trying to select the first span inside the div and then get the strong value. So far I managed to scrape other things successfully, however for this I couldn't get it done:

```
        Document d = Jsoup.connect("http://www.emmacloth.com/Clothing-vc-7061.html?icn=clothing&ici=ec_navbar05").timeout(6000).get();
        Elements elements =  d.select("div#productsContent1_goods.products_category");
    for (Element element: elements.select("div.box-product-list.list_all_items")){
        System.out.println("start");
        String productImage = element.select("div.goods_aImg a img").attr("src");
        String productname = element.select("div.goods_mz a").attr("title");
        String productUrl = "http://www.emmacloth.com" + element.select("div.goods_mz a").attr("href");
 //         String productPrice = element.select("div.product-
list.list_all_items_price.price_new >span.index-price.special_price.final_price").toString();
        Elements priceElements = element.select(
                "div.product-list.list_all_items_price.price_new > span.index-price.special_price.final_price"
        );

        for (Element priceElement : priceElements) {
            System.out.println(priceElement.attr("price"));
        }
//          System.out.println(productPrice);                   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within this `div` you are looking for the `span` which has the following classes: `index-price special_price final_price` and from that (I *think*) you want to extract the `price`.

Given the html provided in your question, the following code ...

```
String html = "<div id=\"cat-product-list\" alt1=\"356623\" class=\"product-list list_all_items_price price_new\">" +
    "<span id=\"wholesale_11_member_price\" class=\"index-price special_price final_price\" price=\"US$5.25\">" +
    "<strong class=\"final_price_strong\">US$5.25</strong>" +
    "<b class=\"show_vip\">(vip)</b>" +
    "</span>" +
    "<span id=\"wholesale_12_member_price\" class=\"index-price special_price final_price\" price=\"US$4.90\" style=\"display: none\">" +
    "<strong class=\"final_price_strong\">US$4.90</strong>" +
    "<b class=\"show_vip\">(vip)</b>" +
    "</span>" +
    "<span id=\"wholesale_13_member_price\" class=\"index-price special_price final_price\" price=\"US$4.55\" style=\"display: none\">" +
    "<strong class=\"final_price_strong\">US$4.55</strong>" +
    "<b class=\"show_vip\">(vip)</b>" +
    "</span>" +
    "<span id=\"wholesale_14_member_price\" class=\"index-price special_price final_price\" price=\"US$4.20\" style=\"display: none\">" +
    "<strong class=\"final_price_strong\">US$4.20</strong>" +
    "<b class=\"show_vip\">(vip)</b>" +
    "</span>" +
    "<span id=\"shop_price_member_price_on\" class=\"index-price shop_price\" price=\"US$7.00\"><strike>US$7.00</strike></span>" +
    "</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

// this selector selects the div(s) having classes: "product-list list_all_items_price price_new"
// and within that div, it selects the span(s) having the classes: "index-price special_price final_price"
Elements priceElements = doc.select(
        "div.product-list.list_all_items_price.price_new > span.index-price.special_price.final_price"
);

for (Element priceElement : priceElements) {
    System.out.println(priceElement.attr("price"));
}
```

... will print out the product prices:

```
US$5.25
US$4.90
US$4.55
US$4.20
```

### **Update**

In response to his comment:

> or some reason its not working for the whole website, can you check my modified question

The following code ...

```
Document d =
        Jsoup.connect("http://www.emmacloth.com/Clothing-vc-7061.html?icn=clothing&ici=ec_navbar05").timeout(6000).get();
for (Element element : d.select("div#productsContent1_goods.products_category > div.box-product-list.list_all_items")) {
    System.out.println("start");
    String productImage = element.select("div.goods_aImg > a > img").attr("src");
    String productname = element.select("div.goods_mz > a").attr("title");
    String productUrl = "http://www.emmacloth.com" + element.select("div.goods_mz > a").attr("href");

    System.out.println(productImage);
    System.out.println(productname);
    System.out.println(productUrl);
}
```

.. will print:

```
http://img.ltwebstatic.com/images/pi/201710/3b/15090086488079557831_thumbnail_220x293.jpg
Pearl Embellished Bow Tied Bell Cuff Blouse
http://www.emmacloth.com/Pearl-Embellished-Bow-Tied-Bell-Cuff-Blouse-p-403325-cat-1733.html
... etc
```

So far, so good. But what about the `price`? If you look at the source of this webpage you'll see that the price element is dynamic content which is provided by the `category_price` JS function on that page. So, that element does not exist *statically* and hence cannot be read by JSoup. In order to read dynamic content you'll have to use a web driver such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: for some reason its not working for the whole website, can you check my modified question

Comment: I have updated the answer, the `price` element is dynamic content so JSoup cannot read it.